# UITabViewController More tab issues

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having issues with a tabbarcontroller, specifically the More tab, and would appreciate some help!

In my AppDelegate I have customized the titlebar to my own color:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)  
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()  

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 102.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)  
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

And this works fine for all tabs APART from the More tab. The More tab now has a completely white titlebar and white text so you can't read it.

Any ideas how to make my color changes apply to the More tab? It seems setting the background image is the line that causes the issue, if I comment this out it works. But, I need that line for one of my other tabs where I need to remove the shadow image at the bottom of the titlebar (you can't remove the shadow image without also having a background image). I don't seem to be able to make it work for both that tab and for the More tab. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you add image of your tab with more tab?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwVdRH2LUd_AVVRvNEo4RFEwWlU

Comment: seems more tab is selected.